# How to make fake webcam effect using video without having webcam?

Tags: windows-xp, webcam

I don't have webcam. but just for fun in Gmail video chat and in skype i want to run a video as a webcam is it possible.

How gmail video chat and skype can play a video as webcam

Any trick or Windows XP 32 bit, portable freeware needed.

Comment: Video to Webcam ( http://www.brothersoft.com/video-to-webcam-243925.html) could make as a virtual webcam, but sadly, it's not free :(

Comment: [YAWCAM](http://www.yawcam.com/) claims to have this feature, and is free, but unfortunately requires Java...

Answer (score 4):

ManyCam? http://www.manycam.com/ (freeware)

Comment: can we emulate webcam with this. have u tried this. it just adds cool graphics to webcam not run video file as a webcam

Comment: I have never used it myself, but have seen others using it to display videos as a webcam.

Comment: It works. Also see http://blog.manycam.com/?p=6 to remove the watermark.

Comment: In recent versions you can't remove the watermark without paying, but it's much smaller and less obtrusive than in other alternatives (logo in bottom right instead of across the middle)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and you may also have noticed) all virtual webcam programs for Windows cost money. Among many others, [Magic Camera](http://www.shiningmorning.com/) is shareware, though, so you can try it for free.

[WebCam Studio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/) is free but only for GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you could try [v4l2loopback with mplayer](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/Mplayer). It’s all free software. Detailed instructions in my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/411897/using-desktop-as-fake-webcam-on-linux/557550#557550).

Answer (score -1):

[OBS Studio's VirtualCam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.539/) would be what you are looking for.