# Creating virtual webcam and microphone on Linux

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, webcam, microphone

I would like to stream a video file into a virtual webcam and microphone. I know how to create a virtual webcam (see [Using desktop as fake webcam on linux](https://superuser.com/questions/411897/using-desktop-as-fake-webcam-on-linux)).

I can play video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -i planet_earth.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

The command above works well, but it only streams the video into `/dev/video0`, and **there is no sound**.

How can I also create a virtual microphone, and play a video **with sound**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553706/11814750