# How to patch sources in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm sure this has been covered before, but it's not making sense to me.

---

If I want to capture the far right of 3 screens (3 wide, 1 high) at 30fps, all of which are 1920x1080, I do this:

```
ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+3840,0 \
    test.mkv
```

([based loosely on this](https://superuser.com/a/713100/405089))

That works, and produces a silent video.  So far, so good.

---

Now I want to add a mono soundtrack to it, taken from channel 3 of a 32-channel USB interface, so I do this to start with???:

```
ffmpeg \
    -f alsa -ac 32 -i plughw:CARD=XUSB,DEV=0 \
    -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+3840,0 \
    test.mkv
```

([based loosely on this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/V4L2_ALSA))

I imagine that that would give me a video file with 32 uncompressed audio tracks.  And once I see that working, I could add one more line to the command to filter out just the one that I want, and then another line or two to compress the audio and video.  But as it is, it still gives me a *silent* video, and a bunch of "ALSA buffer xruns" in the terminal while it's running.

I can't re-patch the hardware to channel 1 (cropped screenshot shown) because channels 1&2 are a stereo pair for a different, simultaneous use, and that receiving app *only* cares about 1&2.  So the broadcast must go there, and I need to pick channel 3 or higher to be the mono soundtrack of the additional recorded video.

[image]

I can't use the broadcast app to record this, because the broadcast needs to be different from the recording, and that app only does one stream.  If it wasn't already tied up, then I *could* use it for this recording (with the audio patched to 1&2), and it would be dead simple.

But since all the components of the recording already exist, I figured I could just add some lines to the startup script to pull it all together behind the scenes.  When the event is done, "Oh look!  There's the recording too!  And it's different from the broadcast, just like we wanted."

I can't imagine that no one has documented this particular use as a working example, albeit with possibly different numbers, but I can't seem to find it.

My specific case is a meeting with some remote participants, with the broadcast feeding the remote people without looping their feeds back to them, and the recording needs to include everyone.
But I can see a nearly identical configuration used for gaming or software demonstrations, etc.

---

Recording audio alone does work, using arecord:

```
arecord \
    --device=plughw:CARD=XUSB,DEV=0 --channels=32 --file-type=wav --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 \
    test.wav
```

That gives me a 32-track wav file, all of which is correct, according to Audacity.
(that's the only format that this interface supports - it just is what it is)

So that gives me a little bit of reassurance that it can work *somehow*.  I just can't seem to find a decent example to take channel 3 or higher as the mono soundtrack to a separate video source.

Comment: Channels are not the same as streams/tracks in ffmpeg. Does `plughw:CARD=XUSB,DEV=0` provide a stream with 32 channels (doubtful), or 32 separate mono streams?

Comment: @llogan I don't know.  It's a USB 2.0 device, and while I've done some token work with the HID interface, I don't know the audio interface very well at all.  I have absolutely no idea what alsa does with it, except that `arecord` with `--channels 32` gives me a single, 32-channel wav file.

Comment: I just rediscovered [the VideoProduction.StackExchange site](https://video.stackexchange.com/).  Would this question fit better over there?

Comment: That site is supposed to be for video production, editing, etc. [unix.se] might be more appropriate. What does ffmpeg show about the `test.wav` from `arecord`? `ffmpeg -i test.wav`

Comment: @llogan Well, this kinda *is* production, albeit an auxiliary function of it.  Anyway, `ffmpeg` on that wav file says `Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s32le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 32 channels, s32, 49152 kb/s`

Comment: I've discovered another problem though: the broadcast app seems to take exclusive control of the audio input, so that another app can't use it.  So the other 30 channels are completely useless anyway.  I'm looking at a separate machine now, with its own feed from the sound board, and a hardware capture device to siphon off the video.  Do you happen to have a solution for *that*, inside the same box?

Comment: The Unix.se users would know more about ALSA than the VP.se crowd. Your new question is too ambiguous for me to provide any input.

Comment: @llogan Ah!  Okay.  The new question is outside the scope of the original anyway: sharing the same multi-channel audio input between different apps that each use different channels of it.  And this whole thing is starting to look very much like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was missing:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#jack

Use that as the audio source instead of ALSA, and it creates a Jack device with whatever name and channel count you gave it on the command line.  The example shown here is 1 channel (mono) named "ffmpeg_meeting".  Then another command (or a UI action) can make the connection(s) to anything you want:

[image]

Of course, Jack has to be installed and running for this to work.  :-)